# Ruby on Rails: How to download a file with send_file and still show a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendfile

I'm sending an email with a link to a downloadable brochure.

Here's my download action

```
def download
    @thing = Thing.find_using_slug(params[:id])

    send_file @thing.brochure.path, 
        :type => 'application/pdf', 
        :filename => "#{@thing.name}_brochure.pdf"
end
```

When the user clicks the link from the email it starts the download and then they are left with a blank screen. I'd like to render a landing page and still send the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a better idea for the link in the email to point to the action for the landing page, perhaps with something like a `?dl` querystring appended.

The landing page action could conditionally check for `params.include?(:dl)`, and if found append Javascript like the following to the `<head>` of the landing page HTML.

```
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location = 'URL TO DOWNLOAD ACTION HERE';
  }, 2000);
}
```

It'd be good practice to also provide a link **on** the landing page *(again, conditional on the presence of the `?dl` querystring)* in case the user has Javascript disabled or doesn't want to wait the 2 seconds for the redirect.